# checking structure of GLobally defined Varray or nested table in PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, nested-table, varray

I am modifying a package. In one of the procedure I got below line.

```
query_det_arr   ecc_query_det_arr_type := ecc_query_det_arr_type(NULL);
```

this `ecc_query_det_arr_type` is not defined anywhere inside the `package`. as per my understanding this must be `varray` or `nested table`.

They may have created using separate create command.

Is there anyway to check what `ecc_query_det_arr_type` contains? I mean any query or anyway in sql developer?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is desc <your_type> like below:

```
desc ecc_query_det_arr_type;
```

**A side note:** Since you are taking a guess here, I thought of writing. It is always better to follow a naming convention for Oracle Objects. In your case I would have created that type like below:

```
         ecc_query_det_ntt if it is nested table type
         ecc_query_det_aat if it is associative array type
         ecc_query_det_vat if it is varray type
```

Comment: it is not giving any output.    Name Null? Type 
---- ----- ----

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is another way:

```
select * from user_source where type = 'TYPE' and lower(name) = 'ecc_query_det_arr_type';
```